# Is there a free realtime spectrograph available for Ubuntu?

Tags: sound

On my home stereo I have a spectrograph that has a 2D matrix, whereby the X axis is the frequency (deep bass on the left, vocals in the center, treble on the right), and the Y axis is the volume or power of the sound at that frequency.  I have seen things like this for Ubuntu, but they work on MP3 files or other pre recorded songs.  Is there anything that can do this real time for a microphone attached or simply the system mixer?

Comment: How about a [webapp](https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/Spectrogram)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This may be a bit overkill, but [Baudline](http://www.baudline.com/) is an incredible real-time FFT spectrogram. It's not in Ubuntu repos, so you will need to [download it on your own](http://www.baudline.com/download.html). It displays a real-time analysis of source signal, but it also allows to analyze pre-recorded data. The brightness of a point represent the power of the sound at this frequency, where horizontal axis represents frequencies, and vertical time - so it kind of shows history of your signal.

It's extensive features make it definitely the most advanced spectrogram available for Linux. It may be a bit too complicated for your uses, though. I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.

[image: baudline screenshot]

Comment: In 2021 baudline will not function at all on the current Ubuntu LTS.   (It requires oss)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jaaa](https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/all/jaaa)

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jaaa/+publishinghistory

[image: Jaaa]

> The JACK & ALSA Audio Analyser, an audio signal generator and spectrum
>   analyser.

---

## [Glfer](https://www.qsl.net/in3otd/glfer.html)

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glfer/+publishinghistory

[image: glfer]

> `glfer` is a GTK+ application with a waterfall spectrum display and slow CW (QRSS) / dual-frequency CW (DFCW) transmitter control interface.
>   [ . . . ]
>   The signal to be analyzed can be acquired in real-time from the sound card or
>   can be read from a `WAV` file.

---

## [Quisk](http://james.ahlstrom.name/quisk/)

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quisk/+publishinghistory

[image: Quisk]

> The Quisk receiver can read the sample data, tune it, filter it, demodulate
>   it, and send the audio to the sound card for output to external headphones or
>   speakers. The Quisk transmitter can accept microphone input and send that to
>   your transmitter via a soundcard or Ethernet.

---

## [Spek](http://spek.cc/)

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spek/+publishinghistory

There is also [Spek](http://spek.cc/), although as of version 0.8.2 it does not work in realtime. However, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/alexkay/spek/issues/98) and a [pull request](https://github.com/alexkay/spek/pull/105) that may change this.

[image: Spek]

> Spek (IPA: /spɛk/, ‘bacon’ in Dutch) helps to analyse your audio files
>   by showing their spectrogram. Spek is free software available for
>   Unix, Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: spek is great, I use it.

Comment: @juanpastas: I've tried to extend your answer, feel free to revert the changes.

Comment: I'm not sure that spek is an answer to the question, because I couldn't find an option to make it work in realtime.

Answer (score 5):

### [Friture](http://friture.org/)

> Friture is a real-time audio analyzer. It works on Windows, macOS and
> Linux. It is free and open source.

[image: Friture GUI]

Answer (score 3):

Baudline still works perfectly fine in 2021, use 'parec' to pull in from Pulse.

`parec --channels=2 --latency-msec=5 | baudline -stdin -channels 2`

Then from within whatever you use to control pulse's audio source, select the app playing audio / the output device to record. It works.

[image: Baudline in 2021 with Pulse]
[Full res image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C2Mb.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The sox tool is able to create a spectrogram:

```
sox Test.wav -n spectrogram -o Test.png
```

- example: https://thepenguin.eu/2017-09-27-create-spectrograms-with-sox/
- documentation with additional options: http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to provide a screenshot (just like other answers do) or a link to the product’s webpage or _any_ information useful for someone who is trying to choose the right tool?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), a very powerful piece of audio software which supports spectrogram or waveform graphs, either in real time or from a pre-recorded. It is free, open source and cross-platform.

[image]

See [the manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html) for how to get this view.

It should be noted that, at least on my laptop, the spectrogram lagged behind real time by a few seconds - if you need absolute real time, the best tool I have found is Friture, mentioned in another answer. However, I've ended up also using Audacity because Friture lacks the ability to analyse existing files.

Answer (score 1):

Sonic Visualiser, initiated and developed in the Centre for Digital Music, Queen Mary University of London.

- https://www.sonicvisualiser.org/
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/sonic-visualiser
- https://github.com/sonic-visualiser/sonic-visualiser

[image: Sonic Visualiser GUI]

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this python snippet searching for the exact same thing and it works quite great: https://gist.github.com/boylea/1a0b5442171f9afbf372

Really simple, you will need to install with `pip3`:

- `numpy`
- `pyqtgraph`
- `pyaudio`
- `PyQt4`

To get it work , I converted the line:

```py
self.img_array = np.zeros((1000, CHUNKSZ/2+1))
```

to:

```py
self.img_array = np.zeros((1000, math.floor(CHUNKSZ/2+1)))
```

to remove the float to int conversion error.

I then ran:

```
python3 script.py
```

Here is a screenshot of the UI:

[image: UI screenshot]

If you develop in Python, funny stuff can be added to this really cool base.